Can I have a cell on a sheet that controls whether a time based trigger sends an email or not?
I use a time based triggered spreadsheet which we fill with data on a Sunday but sends emails out with the data on different days during the week to order eggs for our stalls which are open on different days. We only want to send the email on certain days as the egg company isn't great at dealing with one email that contains all the orders and working out what goes where and when - farmers hey!
This is one of the scripts I use;
function sendSundayList(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("NanaNick");
  var rg=sh.getRange("A10:B17")
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var html='<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>';
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    html+='<tr>';
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      if(i=0) {
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<th>%s</th>',c)
      }else{
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>',c)
      }
    });
    html+='</tr>';
  });
  html+='</table>';
  var email_subj = "Egg Order to NanaNick BananaStall " + Utilities.formatDate(new     Date(), "GMT+1:00", "dd.MM.yyyy");
  MailApp.sendEmail({to: "MrEggman@HenHousefarm.com",subject: email_subj,htmlBody: "Hi     Mr Eggman:<br><br><br>" + html,bcc: 'nananick@shopstall.com'});
 //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),     'Display');//Just a dialog for testing the html
}

I would like to be able to indicate on the spreadsheet that one or more of the stalls didn't require eggs that week and so no email would be sent, by ticking a checkbox or including text like STOP in a cell to stop the script running that week (until the cell is unchecked)
the spreadsheet could look like
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ndVPDtdHtOB77t6WyDjtHJVwjsGFYt72xmogP6Zc0aI/edit?usp=sharing
where AppleAndy is not having eggs this week or would I need to always send out an email but that in 'no egg' weeks it would just say;

No eggs please this week for AppleAndy

I'm not sure that the script can be controlled within the sheet or that there is a better way to deploy it that isn't via a time based trigger

One way to check if a checkbox is checked is by using SpreadsheetApp.Range.isChecked(). Once said that, please ensure that all the relevant details are included directly in the question body. The linked spreadsheet is not shared.

We only want to send the email on certain days You have eight stalls - which day(s) of the week is each email to be sent - stall by stall?

SpreadsheetApp.Range.isChecked() is an option. But, I think it is likely that you will create a "No eggs" Column containing a checkbox on each row (one for each Stall) and you will expand var rg=sh.getRange("A10:B17") to include the checkbox (plus another column where you will enter the day of the week to send the email for each Stall. In that case, perhaps you would use something like: var noEggsFlag = vA[i][2] to get the flag value for a given Stall, and then test it with if(noEggsFlag == true){.

You have eight stalls and a script that will send an email once a week to your supplier. But you want to send separate emails for each stall, send each email on a given day of the week and, even if no eggs are to ordered for a give stall, send a "No eggs" email where necessary.
Consider this answer:

the script should be triggered by a time-driven trigger, daily.
the HTML body isn't required and the body can be simplified because each email deals with a single stall and quantity order.
var rg=sh.getRange("A10:E17"): the data should be extended by two to three Columns

Column C - a "No Eggs" flag using a checkbox
Column D - enter the weekday number for sending the email where Monday = 1.
Column E (optional) - a VLOOKUP formula to display the name of the day that corresponds to the weekday number.

="=> "&vlookup(D10,Assumptions!$A$2:$B$8,2,0) and copied down for each stall.
refer the screenshot of the "Assumptions" sheet.




var today= new Date().getDay() - gets the day number for "Today"
 for (i=0;i<vA.length;i++){ - loop through the vA (data) array
test#1: if (vA[i][3] != today) - should an email for a given Stall be sent today?

If no, then continue reverts to next item in the loop


test#2:  if(noEggsFlag == true){ - is this this a "No eggs" email

if yes, var body = "Hi Mr Eggman\nOur stall: "+stallName+" - no eggs this week thank you\nNanaNick"- send a "No eggs' email
if no, var body = "Hi Mr Eggman\nOur stall: "+stallName+" - please supply "+qty+" eggs this week thank you\nNanaNick" - send an order for the given Stall.




function weeklyEggOrder() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("NanaNick");
  var rg=sh.getRange("A10:E17")
  var vA=rg.getValues()
  var today= new Date().getDay()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Today = "+today) 
  
  // loop through the data looking for emails to be sent today
  for (i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    // test for the "send" day
    var stallName = vA[i][0]
    var noEggsFlag = vA[i][2]
    var email_subj = "Egg order from NanaNick BananaStall: " + Utilities.formatDate(new     Date(), "GMT+1:00", "dd.MM.yyyy");
    if (vA[i][3] != today){
      // don't send email today
      Logger.log("DEBUG: Don't send email today for Stall:"+stallName+" (i="+i+")")
      continue
    }
    var noEggsFlag = vA[i][2]
    if(noEggsFlag == true){
      Logger.log("DEBUG: Send a 'No eggs' email today for Stall:"+stallName+" (i="+i+")")
      var body = "Hi Mr Eggman\nOur stall: "+stallName+" - no eggs this week thank you\nNanaNick"
      //Logger.log(body)
      MailApp.sendEmail({to: "<<insert email>>",subject: email_subj,body:body})
    }else{
    // send an email for an eggs order
    Logger.log("DEBUG: Send an Eggs order today for Stall:"+stallName+" (i="+i+")")
    var qty = vA[i][1]
    var body = "Hi Mr Eggman\nOur stall: "+stallName+" - please supply "+qty+" eggs this week thank you\nNanaNick"
    //Logger.log(body)
    MailApp.sendEmail({to: "<<insert email>>",subject: email_subj,body:body})
    }
  }
}


SAMPLE - Data


SAMPLE - Emails


SAMPLE - Assumptions


SAMPLE - Old html email body



Hi - thanks for your fantastic input - I have been working through and trying to tweak the format a little to make allowances for the different types of eggs that we buy from the farmer.  Boxes of Free Range Egg (Medium)  Boxes of Free Range Egg (Large)  Boxes of Free Range Egg (XL)  Boxes of Whoppers Boxes of Duck eggs Dozens of Quail eggs.

Also struggling to get how  - // loop through the data looking for emails to be sent today - does its thing?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ndVPDtdHtOB77t6WyDjtHJVwjsGFYt72xmogP6Zc0aI/edit?usp=sharing

Also the data is perhaps easier to input from our phones if it is vertical as in the tab Orders - also i have changed how the day is worked so we order on a tues for delivery the next day etc

“trying to tweak the format a little to make allowances for the different types of eggs that we buy from the farmer”. This is something that should have been included in the original question. I suggest that you post a new question.

“Also struggling to get how - // loop through the data looking for emails to be sent today” Create a time-driven trigger.- it’s the first thing mentioned in the answer.

“Also the data is perhaps easier” perhaps another user will submit an answer addressing your concerns.

“trying to tweak the format a little to make allowances for the different types of eggs that we buy from the farmer”. This is something that should have been included in the original question. I suggest that you post a new question.      I did show that we bought different types of eggs in the sheet that I included - perhaps you missed that - but thanks for the input, you have helped me enormously

I did show that we bought different types of eggs in the sheet that I included - perhaps you missed that Yes, I did miss it, why was that? #1: it wasn't mentioned in the original question; #2: the linked spreadsheet was not shared (pointed out in the first comment); #3: link posted eight hours ago is still not shared. You need to make it as easy as possible for users to access your data, and preferably that data is included in the body of the question. It remains now to see whether you think this was a "good" answer.
